How do I use the same SQLalchemy async session in multiple pytests but have the transaction rolled back after each one?
I have a pretty big test setup for each module, and naturally would like to build it only once per module, which means that I need all my tests to run on a single DB session. However, I need the DB state to reset after each test.
I think the best solution for that is to use a single module scoped session fixture alongside a function scoped helper fixture that starts a nested transaction before each test and rolls it back at the end of each test.
However, I can't get it to work. This is the best I was able to come up with:
@pytest_asyncio.fixture(scope="module")
async def setup_session(engine: AsyncEngine) -> AsyncIterator[AsyncSession]:
    connection = await engine.connect()
    transaction = await connection.begin()

    AsyncSessionMaker = sessionmaker(
        connection,
        class_=AsyncSession,
        expire_on_commit=False,
    )

    async_session = AsyncSessionMaker(bind=connection)

    try:
        yield async_session
    finally:
        await async_session.close()
        await transaction.rollback()
        await connection.close()


@pytest_asyncio.fixture(scope="function")
async def session(setup_session: AsyncSession) -> AsyncIterator[AsyncSession]:
    async with setup_session.begin_nested() as transaction:
        try:
            yield setup_session
        finally:
            await transaction.rollback()

Which fails with the error message: Can't operate on closed transaction inside context manager.  Please complete the context manager before emitting further commands.

My guess: within the session fixture, you have to move the await transaction.rollback() to outside of the async with block.

Didn't work, ended up adding a module scoped fixture that truncates every table present in Base's metadata when the module is done.
